# What is counting in the open tab when I open the Superuser?

Tags: support, user-interface

When I'm on Super User, I often see that there is a count in the first opening tag. There is no counting on other sites, I thought that this waS Firefox problem then I opened it in Google Chrome and saw the same issue.

[image]

Comment: @alex I'm new here so don't know much about it, so now I've to ask it there?

Comment: No, it will be automatically migrated to the site once 5 people consider it off topic here. Right now it's got 3 votes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's showing you the number of updated posts since you last looked at that page.  If you click back, you can see a grey button that will show that same number.  You can click it and it'll load in the updated posts inline.

Comment: I'm insure after first sentence that where is the grey button?

Comment: Ok now I got it thanks......

Comment: http://imgur.com/zcOt4 here is a screen shot of it.  edit: whoops, didn't see your latest comment.  You can accept my answer too if it helped. :]

Comment: It seems to me like Facebook now..............